# Applying summation properties to proofs

Tags: cauchy-schwarz-inequality, summation-method

I was given the following statement:

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} p_k = 1$.

And I proved these two statements:

a) $\sum_{k=1}^{n} p_k^2 \geq \frac{1}{n}$ and

b) $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{p_k} \geq n^2$.

Is there a way I can extend the logic to the following statement?

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{p_k^2} \geq n^3$

I assume I can't just take the inverse of statement $a$ and multiply it to statement $b$, and even if I did I would end up with $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{p_k^3} \geq n^3$, which is slightly different than what I'm trying to prove. If there isn't a way, I'll have to start chugging out a cauchy proof! Thank you for your insights.

Comment: I'm not totally sure which statement that is referring to, but if it was to $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{p_k} \geq n^2$, then if $p_1 = p_2 = \frac{1}{2}$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{2} = 4 \geq (2)^2 = 4$ so that statement would be true. If you were referring to the last statement, and $p_1 = p_2 = \frac{1}{2}$, then $p_1^2 = p_2^2 = \frac{1}{4}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{p_k^2} = 8 \geq (2)^3 = 8$ so that statement would be true as well

Comment: What do you mean by "inverse of statement a"? You do know that $\dfrac1{x+y}\ne \dfrac1x+\dfrac1y$, right?

Comment: Sorr, I misread earlier (and have deleted the inaccurate comment).  As to the desired goal, Lagrange Multipliers work.  We want to minimize $\sum \frac 1{p_i^2}$ subject to $\sum p_i=1$.  Lagrange tells us that this minimum is realized when all the $p_i$ are equal, hence $=\frac 1n$.  The claim is clearly true in that case.

Comment: No worries lulu, thank you for trying to help! I ended up just trying to cauchy schwarzs this proof.